# Google Apps Account to be used instead of Google Account for GAE application with a UserProperty

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-account

I would like to ask how to use the Google Apps Account instead of a Google Account if I use the

```
users.create_login_url()
```

function to generate the login page.

Google automatically ask me to login with a Google Account.

If I am running my application with a Google Apps for a specific domain, I have created users within that domain, is there any way that I can let my users to login using the created domain?

for example: hoang@abc.com

and abc.com is the domain managed by Google Apps.

I am an administrator for abc.com, and I have created multiple users within this domain.

Please advice!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify at the time you create the app whether you want to use Google Accounts for authentication, or Google Apps. If you selected Google Accounts for your app, you'll need to create a new app with the authentication setting set correctly in order to use it.

Comment: ohh, thank you Nick, I wonder why Google does not make authentication using Google Accounts or Google Apps flexible after the creation of a new app :-s

Comment: Google seems to be in the process of merging the authentication - I was recently offered to migrate my google apps users to updated version where they can sign-in to all google-accounts related stuff, as if they were google accounts and not google apps accounts.

Comment: That is a good news - the distinction between the two is quite a pain.

Comment: [Relevant blog post by Google Apps team](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/05/more-google-applications-coming-for.html)